# What is the fastest way to initialize an array in C with only two bytes for all elements?

Tags: arrays, c, fill, memcpy, memset

Assume that we have an array called:

```
uint8_t data_8_bit[2] = {color >> 8, color & 0xff};
```

The data is 16-bit color data. Our goal is to create an array called:

```
uint8_t data_16_bit[2*n];
```

Where `n` is actually the length of 16-bit data array. But the array `data_16_bit` cannot hold 16-bit values so therefore I have added a `2*n` as array size.

Sure, I know that I can fill up the array `data_16_bit` by using a for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        data_16_bit[j*i] = data_8_bit[j];
```

But there must be a faster way than this?
`memset` or `memcpy`?

Comment: `i` is not used in the statement `data_16_bit[j*n] = data_8_bit[j];`, so you can remove the redundant loop `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)`.

Comment: Your last code snippet doesn't make much sense. Maybe you should show an example of source data in the `data_8_bit` array and what you want in the `data_16_bit` array at the end of the day.

Comment: It seems that `data_16_bit[j * n]` should rather be `data_16_bit[j + i]`. Please [edit] and clarify

Comment: @Jabberwocky My guess is `data_16_bit[2 * i + j]`

Comment: @MikeCAT possibly

Comment: Why do you want `uint8_t` when you have 16 bit color [instead of `uint16_t`]? You can do: `uint16_t data[1024];` and, then, `data[0] = color;` or `data[0] = bswap_16(color);` The way you're using your array is just a manual/harder way to do `uint16_t`

Comment: If your destination memory block doesn't have **all** its bytes the same (as seems likely), then any trick using `memset` won't work. You'll need a loop of some sort. But you can copy two bytes at a time, using a `for` loop with `i+=2` as its increment.

Comment: I have updated my question. I think memset is good to use, but I don't know how to use it if I have 2 elements. If I would only set 1 element to the 16-bit array, I would use memset.

Comment: If the array contents are all supposed to be the same, sure use `memset`. If you have the array contents already stashed somewhere in memory, sure use `memcpy`. If you have arbitrary data that you know ahead of time, an [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) is also an option, although it's an eyesore for "large" arrays. Are you asking out of curiosity or a technical requirement? Sounds like premature optimization to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO the easiest one to optimize by the compiler (and very safe as well) is

```
void foo(uint16_t color, uint8_t *arr16, size_t n)
{
    uint8_t data_8_bit[2] = {color >> 8, color & 0xff};

    while(n--)
    {
        memcpy(arr16 + n * 2, data_8_bit, 2);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8Wh5Pc3aP

Comment: Isn't this faster to use `data_16_bit += 2;` instead of `arr16 + n * 2` ?

Comment: @MrYui test it youself -you have the link

Comment: Yes! It gave me 56 assembly lines instead of 59.

Comment: @MrYui I have only shown the idea - compilers are better in micropotimizalitions than people. `memcpy` is usually the best idea as compilers understand this function very well

Comment: the compiler isn't able to auto-vectorize this, so it's not quite optimal. @MrYui the number of instructions doesn't say anything. After loop-unrolling the number of instructions would be far more than a simple loop, but it runs much faster. And most other optimizations will also increase instruction count including vectorization due to the alignment setup and trailing elements handling

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you are trying to do is ensure that each element of `data_16_bit` at an even index contains the same value as `data_8_bit[0]`, and each element at an odd index contains the same value as `data_8_bit[1]`.

- Standard C does not provide a way to express such a thing via an initializer.
- `memset()` does not, by itself, provide a solution better than plain iteration because you're trying to set the target bytes to alternating values instead of all to the same value.
- `memcpy()` does not yield any simple approach that is much, if any, better than the simple iterative assignments because the source pattern is only two bytes.  It would be possible to perform fewer than `n` calls to `memcpy()` in the general case, but the code to accomplish that would be fairly complex.

If `n` is a compile-time constant then the fastest approach is to just write out a full initializer:

```
uint8_t data_16_bit[2*8] = {
  color >> 8, color & 0xff,
  color >> 8, color & 0xff,
  color >> 8, color & 0xff,
  color >> 8, color & 0xff,
  color >> 8, color & 0xff,
  color >> 8, color & 0xff,
  color >> 8, color & 0xff,
  color >> 8, color & 0xff
};
```

If `n` is not a compile time constant then

1. you should consider using dynamically-allocated memory instead of a VLA, and
2. you cannot use an initializer.

In that case, something like your `for` loop is probably about as good as it gets.  I would write it like this, though:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n * 2; i += 2) {
    data_16_bit[i] =   data_8_bit[0];
    data_16_bit[i+1] = data_8_bit[1];
}
```

Comment: ***`perform fewer than n calls to memcpy()`*** compiler will generate the code which will not have even a single call to the `memcpy`.

Comment: Yes, you frequently come back to this point, @0___________.  Some compilers will indeed transform at least some `memcpy()` calls, but that's not relevant to my point here, which is as much about source code as it is about whether any calls are actually dispatched to a library function.

Comment: The question is about micro-optimizations. Compilers are usually better if humans do not try to confuse them. It is 21st century

Answer (score 1):

Although quite unknown to many, you can use [`wmemset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wmemset) for this if `sizeof(wchar_t)` is a multiple of 2 on your platform, for example when it's a 2-byte type:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(wchar_t)*CHAR_BIT == 16);

wchar_t pattern;
memcpy(&pattern, data_8_bit, 2);
wmemset((wchar_t*)data_16_bit, pattern, n);
```

If `wchar_t` is a 4-byte type like on most *nix platforms

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(wchar_t)*CHAR_BIT == 32);

wchar_t pattern;
memcpy(&pattern, data_8_bit, 2);
memcpy((char*)&pattern + 2, data_8_bit, 2);
wmemset((wchar_t*)data_16_bit, pattern, n);
```

If `wchar_t` is even bigger (extremely unlikely) then just repeat that those first steps to create the filling pattern

`wmemset` should be **hand-optimized with SIMD in assembly** like `memset` so it'll be extremely fast compared to other solutions where the compiler isn't able to auto-vectorize. For example there are lots of [optimized `memset` and `wmemset` versions for x86-64 in glibc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/) including SSE2, AVX2 [and even AVX-512](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memset-avx512-unaligned-erms.S.html)

Answer (score 0):

We can store into the `uint8_t` array using a `uint16_t` pointer.

This is desirable because the original fill value is 16 bits.

We can even store 64 bits at a time. We replicate the 16 bit color four times to get a `uint64_t` value. We store into the array using a `uint64_t` pointer.

This method is what the builtin `memset` function tries to do [it would try to use XMM registers].

---

Here's what I came up with.

Note that we can start with byte stores if we need to align to an 8 byte boundary [if the arch requires this], then do wide stores in the middle and revert to char/short stores at the end.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void
fill8(uint8_t *data,uint16_t color,size_t len)
{
    uint64_t *p64;
    uint16_t *p16;
    size_t count;

    // NOTE: enhancement would be to align the data pointer to 8 byte boundary
    // by transferring 16 bit data as below

    // get 64 bit color value
    uint64_t c64 = 0;
    c64 = (c64 << 16) | color;
    c64 = (c64 << 16) | color;
    c64 = (c64 << 16) | color;
    c64 = (c64 << 16) | color;

    // get pointer to 64 bit data and its count
    p64 = (uint64_t *) data;
    count = len / sizeof(c64);

    // increment byte pointer and decrement byte length
    data += count * sizeof(c64);
    len -= count * sizeof(c64);

    // transfer data 64 bits at a time
    for (;  count > 0;  --count, ++p64)
        *p64 = c64;

    // get pointer to 16 bit data
    p16 = (uint16_t *) data;
    count = len / sizeof(color);

    // increment byte pointer and decrement byte length
    data += count * sizeof(color);
    len -= count * sizeof(color);

    // transfer data 16 bits at a time
    for (;  count > 0;  --count, ++p16)
        *p16 = color;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> It leads to UB. Strict alising. If platform does not allow unaligned access and *data is unaligned it will result in the exception – 0___________

Unaligned access is *not* a "strict aliasing" violation. It is *unaligned* access. On certain architectures, this will cause an alignment exception [in the hardware]. I addressed this in comments above, but, to be fair, there is a reworked example below that includes the alignment code.

> *Note that we can start with byte stores if we need to align to an 8 byte boundary* Alignment has nothing to do with strict aliasing. It doesn't matter where the data that `uint_t *data` points to - in this function it's of type `uint8_t` and referring to it with a `uint64_t *` pointer unequivocally violates strict aliasing. – Andrew Henle

No, I don't believe it violates "strict aliasing" because it doesn't apply here. You might have more luck with "violates type punning" but I doubt that as well.

The [updated] code [below] is very similar to Freebsd's `memset`.

And, even if the code violated the "rule", there are known workarounds and exceptions:

1. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/06/02/the-joys-and-perils-of-c-and-c-aliasing-part-1
2. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/06/03/the-joys-and-perils-of-aliasing-in-c-and-c-part-2

More detail in the links, but strict aliasing allows the compiler to optimize a function for access to `a` and `b` that is:

```
void func(int *a,long *b)
```

But, it really wants:

```
void func(int * restrict a,long * restrict b)
```

Without the `restrict` the compiler can't do [dubious] optimizations on the pointers because it can't determine if they overlap.

Here, the compiler *can* deduce the pointer relationships and generate correct code because of the way the pointers are set/incremented.

If we must, to be [completely] safe, compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing` [but I don't believe it's required in this instance].

It might be "type punning". But, because the data is `unsigned`, and the relationships are known (e.g. `uint8_t` and `uint64_t`), the generated code will still be correct.

As I mentioned, `memset` does similar pointer/data manipulations. If the code herein is "bad", then `libc` is also broken. See the Freebsd `memset` implementation below.

The pointer alignment issue, which I addressed in comments, *is* valid. Here is some reworked code to address the alignment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <byteswap.h>

#define OFFOF(_ptr) \
    ((uintptr_t) (_ptr))

int opt_b;
int opt_v;

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0);

uint8_t phys[1000000];

void
fill8(uint8_t *data,uint16_t color,size_t len)
{
    uint64_t *p64;
    uint16_t *p16;
    size_t count;

    if (opt_b)
        color = bswap_16(color);

    // NOTE: enhancement would be to align the data pointer to 8 byte boundary
    // by transferring 16 bit data as below
    for (;  (len > 0) && (OFFOF(data) & 0x07);  ++data, --len) {
        *data = color;
        color = bswap_16(color);
    }

    // get 64 bit color value
    uint64_t c64 = 0;
    c64 = (c64 << 16) | color;
    c64 = (c64 << 16) | color;
    c64 = (c64 << 16) | color;
    c64 = (c64 << 16) | color;

    // get pointer to 64 bit data and its count
    p64 = (uint64_t *) data;
    count = len / sizeof(c64);

    // increment byte pointer and decrement byte length
    data += count * sizeof(c64);
    len -= count * sizeof(c64);

    // transfer data 64 bits at a time
    for (;  count > 0;  --count, ++p64)
        *p64 = c64;

    // transfer data 8 bits at a time
    for (;  len > 0;  ++data, --len) {
        *data = color;
        color = bswap_16(color);
    }
}

void
verify(size_t len,size_t align)
{
    uint8_t *data;
    size_t idx;
    uint8_t val;

    data = &phys[0];
    for (idx = 0;  idx < align;  ++idx) {
        val = data[idx];
        if (val != 0)
            sysfault("verify: BEF idx=%zu val=%2.2X\n",idx,val);
    }

    data = &phys[align];
    for (idx = 0;  idx < len;  ++idx) {
        val = data[idx];

        if (opt_v) {
            printf(" %2.2X",val);
            if ((idx % 16) == 15)
                printf("\n");
        }

        if (val == 0)
            sysfault("verify: DAT idx=%zu val=%2.2X\n",idx,val);
    }

    if (opt_v)
        printf("\n");

    data = &phys[align + len];
    for (idx = 0;  idx < align;  ++idx) {
        val = phys[idx];
        if (val != 0)
            sysfault("verify: AFT idx=%zu val=%2.2X\n",idx,val);
    }
}

void
dotest(int tstno,size_t len,size_t align)
{
    uint8_t *data = phys;

    memset(phys,0,sizeof(phys));

    while (1) {
        uintptr_t off = data - phys;
        if (off == align)
            break;
        ++data;
    }

    if ((tstno > 1) && opt_v)
        printf("\n");
    printf("T:%d %p L:%zu A:%zu\n",tstno,data,len,align);

    uint16_t color = 0x0102;
    fill8(data,color,len);

    verify(len,align);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int tstno = 1;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch(cp[-1]) {
        case 'b':  // big endian
            opt_b = ! opt_b;
            break;
        case 'v':  // verbose check
            opt_v = ! opt_v;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (size_t len = 1;  len <= 128;  ++len) {
        for (size_t align = 0;  align < 8;  ++align, ++tstno)
            dotest(tstno,len,align);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is [one of] Freebsd's `memset` implementations:

```
/*-
 * Copyright (c) 1990, 1993
 *  The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * This code is derived from software contributed to Berkeley by
 * Mike Hibler and Chris Torek.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3. Neither the name of the University nor the names of its contributors
 *    may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
 *    without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
 * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

#if defined(LIBC_SCCS) && !defined(lint)
static char sccsid[] = "@(#)memset.c    8.1 (Berkeley) 6/4/93";
#endif /* LIBC_SCCS and not lint */
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
__FBSDID("$FreeBSD$");

#include <sys/types.h>

#include <limits.h>

#define wsize   sizeof(u_int)
#define wmask   (wsize - 1)

#ifdef BZERO
#include <strings.h>

#define RETURN  return
#define VAL 0
#define WIDEVAL 0

void
bzero(void *dst0, size_t length)
#else
#include <string.h>

#define RETURN  return (dst0)
#define VAL c0
#define WIDEVAL c

void *
memset(void *dst0, int c0, size_t length)
#endif
{
    size_t t;
#ifndef BZERO
    u_int c;
#endif
    u_char *dst;

    dst = dst0;
    /*
     * If not enough words, just fill bytes.  A length >= 2 words
     * guarantees that at least one of them is `complete' after
     * any necessary alignment.  For instance:
     *
     *  |-----------|-----------|-----------|
     *  |00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|0A|00|
     *            ^---------------------^
     *       dst         dst+length-1
     *
     * but we use a minimum of 3 here since the overhead of the code
     * to do word writes is substantial.
     */
    if (length < 3 * wsize) {
        while (length != 0) {
            *dst++ = VAL;
            --length;
        }
        RETURN;
    }

#ifndef BZERO
    if ((c = (u_char)c0) != 0) {    /* Fill the word. */
        c = (c << 8) | c;   /* u_int is 16 bits. */
#if UINT_MAX > 0xffff
        c = (c << 16) | c;  /* u_int is 32 bits. */
#endif
#if UINT_MAX > 0xffffffff
        c = (c << 32) | c;  /* u_int is 64 bits. */
#endif
    }
#endif
    /* Align destination by filling in bytes. */
    if ((t = (long)dst & wmask) != 0) {
        t = wsize - t;
        length -= t;
        do {
            *dst++ = VAL;
        } while (--t != 0);
    }

    /* Fill words.  Length was >= 2*words so we know t >= 1 here. */
    t = length / wsize;
    do {
        *(u_int *)dst = WIDEVAL;
        dst += wsize;
    } while (--t != 0);

    /* Mop up trailing bytes, if any. */
    t = length & wmask;
    if (t != 0)
        do {
            *dst++ = VAL;
        } while (--t != 0);
    RETURN;
}
```

Comment: It leads to UB. Strict alising. If platform does not allow unaligned access and *data is unaligned it will result in the exception

Comment: @0___________ [Although not shown in the code] this was covered in the 2nd paragraph of the 2nd section of my answer and in the NOTE: comment in the code example. It's overkill/moot if the buffer came from `malloc`: _The  malloc()  and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any  built-in  type._ Also, `attribute((aligned(sizeof(uint64_t)))` could be used. And, OP is talking about filling a frame buffer that has `uint16_t` color values, so use of `uint8_t *` to define the buffer was arbitrary.

Comment: @CraigEstey *Note that we can start with byte stores if we need to align to an 8 byte boundary*  Alignment has nothing to do with strict aliasing.  It doesn't matter where the data that `uint_t *data` points to - in this function it's of type `uint8_t` and referring to it with a `uint64_t *` pointer unequivocally violates strict aliasing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Um, no, I have to disagree on this. Please see the UPDATE to my answer

Comment: *... the generated code will still be correct*  That's not based on anything in the C standard.  It's based on mere ***hope***.  And you can't use any example from an *implementation* such as the BSD `memset()` example to show otherwise - the *implementation* can rely on it's own implementation specifics, you can't.  What happens if the implementation changes?  What happens if it gets ported to a newer CPU that offers faster instructions provided super alignment restrictions are implicitly met - that your code would then break because of strict aliasing? ***Hope*** is not something to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions to consider.

1. Once initialized, will this data be read-only, or modifiable?
2. Is the number of elements fixed? configurable at build time? or varies at runtime?
3. Is there a reasonable limit to the maximum number elements?
4. How many times will you need to initialize your buffer?

Beginning with the third question, it looks like you will have a maximum of 65536 unique sets as you are dealing with a 16-bits of data. If you are willing to sacrifice a bit of space for speed, you can create a 64 kB global table that contains all the permutations in the order that you expect. The end result is that you have the table loaded into memory automatically as it would reside in one of the data sections in your executable. How you create/populate this table is up to you. (For example, you could manually create the table, or you could have a dedicated step in your build process that both creates and compiles it into a linkable object file.)

Continuing on, assuming that your table is loaded into memory.

If your pre-populated table is at least as large as what you will ever need, you can either ...

1. Return a pointer to the table if the contents will never change (and best to have it reside in read-only data section for this case). The benefit is that no more data needs to be copied--you only need to move a pointer around.
2. Use a memory copying routine such as memcpy() (or a custom one if you don't want what the compiler generates) to copy from the pre-populated table to your desired buffer if the contents are going to change, or if your destination buffer is larger than your 64 kB pre-populated table.

Comment: It's free to modify.